# Redirect links from main to subdomain

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration, redirect

I move part of my site to subdomain and want that link of that component redirect to subdomain. I want if user come to site with moved component link he will redirect to subdomain.

> https://domain.com/cat/item -> https://sub.domain.com/cat/item

Need some code in htaccess. Please help with

Answer (score 1):

You can find many answers searching around. My favorite reference:

**.htaccess Snippets**
https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

You can start with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```